# Difference between -shared and -Wl,-shared of the GCC options

Tags: linux, unix, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I know `-Wl,-shared` is a option of **ld**. I've seen some person compile like this,

```
$ gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libtest.so -o libtest.so *.o
```

And some person like this

```
$ gcc -Wl,-shared -Wl,-soname,libtest.so -o libtest.so *.o
```

So, I want to know if there is some difference between `-shared` and `-Wl,-shared`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There *is* a difference between passing `-shared` to gcc or `-shared` to ld (via `-Wl`). Passing `-shared` to GCC may enable or disable other flags at link time. In particular, different `crt*` files might be involved.

To get more information, grep for `-shared` in GCC's `gcc/config/` directory and subdirectories.

**Edit:** To give a specific example: on i386 FreeBSD, `gcc -shared` will link in object file `crtendS.o`, while without `-shared`, it will link in `crtend.o` instead. Thus, `-shared` and `-Wl,-shared` are not equivalent.

Comment: In the current gcc's svn trunk, I found the following comments at line 85 in gcc/config/i386/linux.h. "Provide a LINK_SPEC appropriate for Linux.  Here we provide support for the special GCC options -static and -shared, which allow us to link things in one of these three modes by applying the appropriate combinations of options at link-time."

Comment: Hi, FX, could you give out a more concrete explanation? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is any difference. `-shared` is not a supported option of `gcc` and it is passed to linker whether you specify it with `-Wl` or not. `-Wl` option of gcc is used to specify that a comma separated list of options is to be passed to linker for further processing.

Comment: There is a diff. In my case, project won't compile with -Wl.