# How does gcc `-shared` option affect the output?

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries

Technically, in terms of file content, what is the difference between the output of `gcc -fPIC -shared src.c` and `gcc -fPIC src.c`?

Assume that `int main(int, char**)` is defined in `src.c` so that both compilations succeed. But executing the `a.out` generated by `gcc -shared src.c`, as expected, gave the following error:

`-bash: ./a_shared.out: cannot execute binary file`

Even if there is a `main` function it it.

Also, how can I inspect the difference in the output files using tools like `otool` or `objdump`?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Shared libraries and executables use the same format: they are both loadable images.  However,

1. Shared libraries are usually position-independent, executables are often not.  This affects code generation: for position-independent, you have to load globals or jump to functions using relative addresses.
2. Executables have an "entry point" which is where execution starts.  This is usually *not* `main()`, because `main()` is a function, and functions return, but execution should never return from the entry point.

Now, this doesn't answer the question about what `-shared` does.  You can ask GCC by using the `-v` flag.  Here are the differences on my system between an invocation without and with `-shared`.

#### Parameters for `collect2` without `-shared`:

```
-dynamic-linker
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/crtbegin.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/crtend.o
```

#### Parameters for `collect2` with `-shared`:

```
-shared
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/crtbeginS.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/crtendS.o
```

#### Observations

It looks like code generation is not affected: you still have to use `-fpic` or `-fPIC`.

You can see that `crt1.o` (the "C runtime") is only included when linking the executable.  Using `nm`, we can find out what it contains:

```
$ nm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
0000000000000000 R _IO_stdin_used
0000000000000000 D __data_start
                 U __libc_csu_fini
                 U __libc_csu_init
                 U __libc_start_main
0000000000000000 T _start
0000000000000000 W data_start
                 U main
```

So you can see it seems to define something to do with `stdin`, as well as `_start` (which is the entry point), and it has an undefined reference to `main`.

I'm not sure what the rest of the files are, but at least you know how to find them and you can poke around, or look at the source code if you like.

Comment: Fantastic - Thank you @dietrich. The part on when `crt1.o` makes the difference clear.

Answer (score 4):

As per https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options  **-shared** option does the following

> - Produce a shared object which can then be linked with other objects to form an executable.
> - Not all systems support this option.
> - For predictable results, you must also specify the same set of options used for compilation (-fpic, -fPIC, or model suboptions) when you specify this linker option.

As per [Difference between -shared and -Wl,-shared of the GCC options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623915/difference-between-shared-and-wl-shared-of-the-gcc-options)  Passing **-shared** to GCC may enable or disable other flags at link time.

As per my understanding if an executable has shared library, **size of executable is very less**.  The executable will not run until the shared library is present and correctly linked. Advantage of using shared library is that if we have a very big code base, **we need not build the entire code always** every time. We **just need to rebuild the .so file**  and link it to executable. This **saves a lot of time**.

And in case for an executabe **without shared library**, executable **size will be very large**. For every code change **entire code needs to be builded**, which can be **very time consuming**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @rohit. I know `-share` produces a shared object, but just wonder how its content differs from that of an executable produced by `gcc` without `-shared`.

Comment: It's shared object, so it's not an executable. That's why you get the error. Are you asking what the difference between a shared object and an executable is?

Comment: Thanks, @RossRidge. Dietrich's answer is exactly what I am interested  in - How an executable is different from a shared object given that they are in the same format.