# -fPIC and -shared meaning?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have a command line like this:

```
$ gcc -shared -fPIC procmem.c -o libprocmem.so
```

But i don't know what -shared and -fPIC mean? Can someone explain it to me. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GCC -fPIC option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311515/gcc-fpic-option)

Comment: @PaulR what about shared ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does gcc `-shared` option affect the output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084855/how-does-gcc-shared-option-affect-the-output)

Comment: TL;DR: use `-shared -fPIC` when compiling shared libraries, so that code can be loaded at an arbitrary address at run-time.