# Relocation compiling issue with shared flags

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I have a program in C that uses the GSL to integrate an ODE system, and store the resulting data in arrays. The code is at the end of the question, but as you'll see it's not really the issue here.

Secondary to the C code, I use a Python script to pass the array pointers into the C code using ctypes, since I later want to plot and manipulate the array data. All of which is fine, it worked with small test programs. But to do so, I need to create a shared library using gcc. Here's where things go wrong.

When I compile with

```
    gcc ctest.c -o ctest.o  -std=c11 -Wall -g -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

the code works fine. I have a main function that replicates the Python script for testing, and nothing breaks. FYI, the `-lgsl` and `-lgslcblas` flags are used to make the linker stop complaining about GSL declarations being missing.  But when I try to create the shared library with

```
    gcc ctest.c -o ctest.o  -std=c11 -Wall -g -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -fPIC -Wl,-shared,-soname,ctest.so
```

gcc spits out this error:

```
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS): In function `__libc_csu_init':
    (.text+0xe): undefined reference to `__init_array_start'
    /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined hidden symbol `__init_array_start' can not be used when making a shared object
    /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: final link failed: Bad value
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Which baffles me. I looked around online, and it seems to be a problem with object initialization, which is still odd to me since I only use built in types for array creation, unless it's GSL screwing up.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_odeiv2.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_complex_math.h>

#define pi M_PI

//#define HAVE_INLINE

typedef struct funcParams {
    double I;
    double J;
    double s;
} funcParams;

int diff (double t, const double y[], double dy[], void * params) {

    #define I() IJs.I
    #define J() IJs.J
    #define s() IJs.s

    #define w1 y[0]
    #define w2 y[1]
    #define w3 y[2]
    #define e1 y[3]
    #define e2 y[4]
    #define e3 y[5]
    #define e4 y[6]

    t = 0;

    funcParams IJs = *(funcParams*) params;

    dy[0] = 2*pi * ( (1-J() /I() )*( 6*(1-2*e1*e1-2*e2*e2)*(e2*e3+e1*e4) - w2*w3) + w3*s() );
    dy[1] = 0;
    dy[2] = 2*pi * ( (J() /I() -1)*(12*(e1*e3-e2*e4)*(e2*e3+e1*e4) - w1*w2) - w1*s() );
    dy[3] = pi * (w3*e2 + w1*e4 - e3*(w2-s()+1));
    dy[4] = pi * (w1*e3 - w3*e1 + e4*(w2-s()-1));
    dy[5] = pi * (-w1*e2 + w3*e4 + e1*(w2-s()+1));
    dy[6] = pi * (-w1*e1 - w3*e3 - e2*(w2-s()-1));

    return GSL_SUCCESS;
}

void quat2C( double* e, double C[3][3]) {

    #undef e1
    #undef e2
    #undef e3
    #undef e4

    #define e1 e[0]
    #define e2 e[1]
    #define e3 e[2]
    #define e4 e[3]

    C[0][0] = 1 - 2*e2*e2 - 2*e3*e3;
    C[0][1] = 2 * (e1*e2 - e3*e4);
    C[0][2] = 2 * (e3*e1 + e2*e4);
    C[1][0] = 2 * (e1*e2 + e3*e4);
    C[1][1] = 1 - 2 * e3*e3 - 2 * e1*e1;
    C[1][2] = 2 * (e2*e3 - e1*e4);
    C[2][0] = 2 * (e3*e1 - e2*e4);
    C[2][1] = 2 * (e2*e3 + e1*e4);
    C[2][2] = 1 - 2 * e1*e1 - 2 * e2*e2;

    return;
}



void timeHistories (double nut0, double x, double vf, int N, double I, double J, double s, double* states, double * nut, double* gamma, double* beta, double* dLambda) {

    funcParams IJs = {I, J, s};
    gsl_odeiv2_system sys = {diff, NULL, 7, &IJs};
    gsl_odeiv2_driver* d = gsl_odeiv2_driver_alloc_y_new(&sys, gsl_odeiv2_step_rkf45, 1e-6, 1e-6, 0.0);

    double* states_i = (double*)malloc(7*sizeof(double));
    states_i[0] = 0;
    states_i[1] = x;
    states_i[2] = 0;
    states_i[3] = sin(nut0*pi/360);
    states_i[4] = 0;
    states_i[5] = 0;
    states_i[6] = cos(nut0*pi/360);
    double v = 0.0;

    double C[3][3];

    /* retrieve the states at each time. This allows us to modify each of the
       "returned" arrays in the same loop */
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {

        double vi = i*vf/N; // current revolution value
        printf("vi got\n");
        gsl_odeiv2_driver_apply(d, &v, vi, states_i); // get states
        printf("states got\n");
        quat2C(&states_i[3],C);
        printf("C got\n");

        printf("%d: %f %f %f %f %f %f %f\n", i, states_i[0], states_i[1], states_i[2], states_i[3], states_i[4], states_i[5], states_i[6]);
    }

    return;
}

int main() {

    double I = 450;
    double J = 75;
    int N = gsl_pow_int(2,14);

    double* states = (double*)malloc(N*sizeof(double));
    double* nut = (double*)malloc(N*sizeof(double));
    double* gamma = (double*)malloc(N*sizeof(double));
    double* beta = (double*)malloc(N*sizeof(double));
    double* dLambda = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double));

    double vf = 4;

    double nut0 = 6;
    double x = 20;
    double s = 0;
    timeHistories(nut0, x, vf, N, I, J, s, states, nut, gamma, beta, dLambda);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are `libgsl` and `libgslcblas`?  If they're `*.a` static archives, were they compiled with `-fPIC` also?

Comment: @Andrew Henle From a quick search in `/usr`, the gsl libraries appear to be .so files (`libsgsl.so` is inside `/usr/local/lib`, although `libgsl.la` also exists in that folder). I don't know if the libraries themselves were compiled with `-fPIC`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I think you may have the answer. It seems that the linker defaults to using libgsl.a. I tried forcing gcc to use the `.so` files with `gcc ctest.c -o ctest.o -I/home/alessandro/Documents/libgsl.so -I/home/alessandro/Documents/libgslcblas.so -std=c11 -Wall -g -lm -fPIC -Wl,-shared,-soname,ctest.so` after copying over the shared libraries from the original folder, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Wait, you're using *uninstalled* copies of the libraries?  This is a recipe for disaster, because the dynamic linker needs to be able to locate the GSL shared libraries at run time.  Are you sure you do not have and cannot get and use your distro's pre-packaged GSL?  It is very likely that there is one.

Comment: Simplify.  Eliminate anything not needed, and split your compilation and link steps.  `gcc -c -std=c11 -fPIC -g -o ctest.o ctest.c` then `gcc -shared -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -o libctest.so ctest.o`.  You can also add `-Wl,-t` to the link step so the `ld` command that does the actual linking will emit trace information for all the files used in the link step.

Comment: To answer both your questions: At John Bollinger I do have gsl installed (Mint has the gsl-bin package, but it didn't contain the libraries itself, or had some other issue). I think that even if I fed gcc the single uninstalled library files, they would have referenced the installed libraries anyway. @AndrewHenle Doing so produces interesting results. It compiles, but when called via python the first gsl function link is missing. Removing -shared reveals that the linker cannot find the gsl or the standard math library, despite those flags being provided.

Comment: *the linker cannot find ... the standard math library*  That tells me there's something seriously wrong with your environment, your system, or both.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I've found the issue. Your answer worked, but it had the library flags before the input file. Switching them allows the file to compile correctly, -shared or not. When -shared is included, Python can correctly use libctest.so and any functions inside. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andrew Henle, the issue has been resolved. Splitting the compilation and linking using

```
gcc -c -std=c11 -fPIC -g -o ctest.o ctest.c && gcc -o libctest.so ctest.o -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -shared
```

produces a shared executable callable by Python (via ctypes, anyway). I'm unsure as to why, but using `-shared` works as opposed to passing commands to the linker with `-Wl,-shared`.

Comment: Passing `-shared` to `gcc` does more than just pass `-shared` to `ld`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25084855/119527) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4623915/119527).